# Recyclerview passing ID from array to another activity onClick returns random id

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview which onClicked should returns its current `PROJECT_ID` and passes it to another activty, But **now im getting a random PROJECT_ID**.
(please remember im not telling about `getAdapterPosition()`, i need the current item `PROJECT_ID` from my ArrayList)

```
int i;
     RecyclerViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    mProjectName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_name);
                    mProjectCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_city);
                    mProjectType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_type);
                    mImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_image);
                    mCheck = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_fav);
                    mProjectStatus = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.label);
                    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            projectid = PROJECT_ID.get(i);
                            Intent in = new Intent(v.getContext(), HomeRecyclerDetailActivity.class);
                            in.putExtra("PID",projectid);
                            v.getContext().startActivity(in);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
      @Override
            public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                v1 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);
                return new RecyclerViewHolder(v1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {    
     SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MirSP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    String offlinejson = pref.getString("OFFLINEJSON", "");
                    if (!offlinejson.equals("")) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(offlinejson);
                            JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
                            Length = data.length();
                            PROJECT_ID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            PROJECT_TITLE = new ArrayList<String>();
                            PROJECT_CITY = new ArrayList<String>();
                            PROJECT_TYPE = new ArrayList<String>();
                            PROJECT_IMAGE = new ArrayList<String>();
                            PROJECT_STATUS = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0, count = data.length(); j < count; j++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject json = data.getJSONObject(j);
                                    int name = json.getInt(TAG_ID);
                                    PROJECT_ID.add(name);
                                    String name1 = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_TITLE);
                                    PROJECT_TITLE.add(name1);
                                    String name2 = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_CITY);
                                    PROJECT_CITY.add(name2);
                                    String name3 = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_TYPE);
                                    PROJECT_TYPE.add(name3);
                                    String name4 = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_IMAGE);
                                    PROJECT_IMAGE.add(name4);
                                    String name5 = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_STATUS);
                                    PROJECT_STATUS.add(name5);
                                    Log.e("JSON OFFLINE NAME", String.valueOf(PROJECT_ID));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                         projecttitle = PROJECT_TITLE.get(i);
                         projectcity = PROJECT_CITY.get(i);
                         projecttype = PROJECT_TYPE.get(i);
                         projectimage = PROJECT_IMAGE.get(i);
                        projectstatus = PROJECT_STATUS.get(i);
        //             Set the values
                        viewHolder.mProjectName.setText(projecttitle);
                        viewHolder.mProjectCity.setText(projectcity);
                        viewHolder.mProjectType.setText(projecttype);

                        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(projectimage, viewHolder.mImage, options);
```

Comment: From where getting `i` in  `RecyclerViewHolder `?

Comment: Is PROJECT_ID is your object and i is your position?

Comment: you need to use getPosition() instead of i here.

Comment: change projectid = PROJECT_ID.get(getAdapterPosition()) it will get you PROJECT_ID of current item in arraylist or use  OnClickListener  in onBindViewHolder()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setOnClickListener` inside `onBindViewHolder` see below your modifyied your code and remove `setOnClickListener` from `RecyclerViewHolder`

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {    
 SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MirSP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                String offlinejson = pref.getString("OFFLINEJSON", "");
                if (!offlinejson.equals("")) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(offlinejson);
                        JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
                        Length = data.length();
                        PROJECT_ID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        PROJECT_TITLE = new ArrayList<String>();
                        PROJECT_CITY = new ArrayList<String>();
                        PROJECT_TYPE = new ArrayList<String>();
                        PROJECT_IMAGE = new ArrayList<String>();
                        PROJECT_STATUS = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int j = 0, count = data.length(); j < count; j++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject json = data.getJSONObject(j);
                                int name = json.getInt(TAG_ID);
                                PROJECT_ID.add(name);
                                String name1 = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_TITLE);
                                PROJECT_TITLE.add(name1);
                                String name2 = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_CITY);
                                PROJECT_CITY.add(name2);
                                String name3 = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_TYPE);
                                PROJECT_TYPE.add(name3);
                                String name4 = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_IMAGE);
                                PROJECT_IMAGE.add(name4);
                                String name5 = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_STATUS);
                                PROJECT_STATUS.add(name5);
                                Log.e("JSON OFFLINE NAME", String.valueOf(PROJECT_ID));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                     projecttitle = PROJECT_TITLE.get(i);
                     projectcity = PROJECT_CITY.get(i);
                     projecttype = PROJECT_TYPE.get(i);
                     projectimage = PROJECT_IMAGE.get(i);
                    projectstatus = PROJECT_STATUS.get(i);
    //             Set the values
                    viewHolder.mProjectName.setText(projecttitle);
                    viewHolder.mProjectCity.setText(projectcity);
                    viewHolder.mProjectType.setText(projecttype);
                    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // below way you can pass any value
                            projectid = PROJECT_ID.get(i);
                            Intent in = new Intent(v.getContext(), HomeRecyclerDetailActivity.class);
                            in.putExtra("PID",projectid);
                            v.getContext().startActivity(in);
                        }
                    });

                    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(projectimage, viewHolder.mImage, options);
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to be OPP's guy it will save you time and hustle.

in your `onBindViewHolder()` use the position of the item to get the item in the ArrayList,

```
Item someItem = list.get(i);
```

Once you get that item you can get the `PROJECT_ID` from that item

```
someItem.getProjectID();
```

I am assuming that you will make a model class for the `Item` to represent item list in the `adapter`

you can populate your list like this

```
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0, count = data.length(); j < count; j++) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = data.getJSONObject(j);
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setProject_ID(""+json.getInt(TAG_ID));
            item.setProject_ID(""+json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_TITLE));
            item.setProject_ID(""+json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_CITY));
            item.setProject_ID(""+json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_TYPE));
            item.setProject_ID(""+json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_IMAGE));
            item.setProject_ID(""+json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_STATUS));
            items.add(item);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

something like this

```
public class Item {

    private String project_ID;
    private String project_Title;
    private String project_City;
    private String project_Type;
    private String project_Image;
    private String project_Status;

    public String getProject_ID() {
        return project_ID;
    }

    public void setProject_ID(String project_ID) {
        this.project_ID = project_ID;
    }

    public String getProject_Title() {
        return project_Title;
    }

    public void setProject_Title(String project_Title) {
        this.project_Title = project_Title;
    }

    public String getProject_City() {
        return project_City;
    }

    public void setProject_City(String project_City) {
        this.project_City = project_City;
    }

    public String getProject_Type() {
        return project_Type;
    }

    public void setProject_Type(String project_Type) {
        this.project_Type = project_Type;
    }

    public String getProject_Image() {
        return project_Image;
    }

    public void setProject_Image(String project_Image) {
        this.project_Image = project_Image;
    }

    public String getProject_Status() {
        return project_Status;
    }

    public void setProject_Status(String project_Status) {
        this.project_Status = project_Status;
    }
}
```